# Can a Web App launch a PDF in a Native App on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, web-applications

As the title says, I have a web application that I run in Safari on my iPad that I would like to launch another app (native to iPad) in order to edit a PDF.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the PDF live?  If it is hosted online, accessible via a URL, I think you could make it work.

A web application can launch a native application if the native application has registered a custom URL scheme (via it's info.plist).  But it's not directly possible for the web app to detect if the native app is installed.

Assuming the native app has a URL scheme registered, e.g. "myapp://com.mycompany.myapp" then the web app could launch it and pass the url to the pdf simply by navigating to a special url with the pdf url passed as a parameter:

```
myapp://com.mycompan.myapp?pdf=http://someserver.com/afile.pdf
```

You probably want to URL-encode the url to the pdf itself...

Comment: I will certainly try this. Can you also explain how I find the package name of the app I want in order to do this? I'm a newbie with the iPad.

Comment: well, in all likelihood you wont be able to do this unless you're the developer of the native app - sorry I misunderstood; I thought you were.  You could contact the developer and request they add such a feature and ask them what their URL scheme is.

Answer (score 0):

it's not an pure solution but maybe [phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/) could allow you to open native applications.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented csv importing functionality into my app; by adding all those entries around `CFBundleDocumentTypes` to the Info.plist.

And if I open a csv-file in safari my app is available in the "Open with..." list.
So if the app is able to edit pdf-files it should register itself as an editor of pdfs, and then it will show up if pdf files are opened in safari.