# iPhone standard UI details

Tags: iphone

Are there any UI standards with respect to font size, color, height of a section header in table view, padding, image size in a table cell etc. If yes, can you please guide me where can I found them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read through [Apple's Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html), if you haven't done so already.

Comment: using any framework like [jqtouch](http://jqtouch.com/) or [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) gives more then that guide ... which makes you do a lot of basic configurations

Comment: I don't see your point. Why would you want to use jquery mobile as a reference to UI standards? And what is wrong with reading the interface guideline put forth by the company who will ultimately decide on whether your app is made available to the public?

Comment: But then you seem to answer questions that explicitly ask for solutions in native apps with suggestions to use javascript frameworks instead. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155942/can-a-web-app-launch-a-pdf-in-a-native-app-on-the-ipad/4156091#4156091). Maybe your focus is a little biased ;)

Comment: But this do not answer queries like image size when put in a table cell, what should be the row height etc.

Comment: Why not, you know, query the view/text/images properties yourself? The information's all there. And why do you even need this information?

Comment: I am developing a new app and wanted to follow all UI standard and guidelines before hand rather than doing modifications at later stage. Also, this has lot of business importance.

Answer (score 0):

you could use https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/tree/master/themes/apple/ as a reference

Comment: I do not see any details on this link. Is this the correct one?

Comment: Are you talking about https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/blob/master/themes/apple/theme.css. I am not able to understand this CSS file.

Comment: have a look on this [demo](http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/) it will give you idea what means each class in this css